# PHP - How to convert an integer number with leading zeros to string?

Tags: php

I want to convert an integer number to string while maintaining the leading `0`'s.

Is this posible in `PHP`?

```
$num = 0000003;

echo $num; // output: 3

echo (string)$num; // output: 3

// Wanted output: "0000003"
```

**Edit**:

I read the most questions before in SO, but I was curious if there was a possibility to keep the `0` and convert it to string in runtime, like the code example above `echo (string)$num;`.

Comment: Simply: you can't. You need to use ```str_pad``` see link by @diiN_

Comment: @MichaelHirschler - So it's **imposible** to convert an integer with leading zero to an string?

Comment: @aldanux The point is that PHP or any other language does not store an integer with leading zeroes

Comment: @aldanux Just because you write `$num = 00003;` does not mean that PHP has stored the leading zeroes. It is stored in memory as `3` as leading zeroes in an integer are irrelevant

Answer (score 6):

you cant. **0000003** in the **runtime** is just **3**.

you can add **zeros** manually using **str_pad** but you have to know target string **length**

```
str_pad((string)$num, $targetLenght, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

Comment: Not sure why this got so much abuse? Unless this was not the first version of the answer

Comment: i just added after 2/3mins info about str_pad. first version was only about 3 === 0000003

Comment: Ah, the difference between the _fastest answer_ and a _good answer_ is obviously 3 downvotes

Answer (score 3):

You have to instantiate the number as a string:

```
$num = "0000003";
```

If you instantiate it as number, it will be treated as such and your 0s will be lost.

Comment: Thanks.. I know but what I want is to convert it as string `00003` to `"00003"`

Comment: Where is your 00003 comming from? You can't convert it directly, but if it is read from DB or input maybe you can read it as string.

Comment: In a function for example: `do_something(00003);` I can not influence the input before

Comment: no you can not, but that 00003 does not just magiaclly appear, if that is php generated it will be either 3 or "00003" instead of 00003 as a number 00003 simply can not exist. If that is some user or DB input, it must be handled at read time. Btw, php will allways read unknown format of 00003 as a string from input or DB. Could you expand your code example to show us where that 00003 comes from?

Comment: see thing is that like RiggsFolly has mentioned in the comment, a number 00003 simply can not exist, once it is stored in mem it will either be stored as 3 or as "00003" (depending on how it is created).

Comment: It can be a random number like `00123` or `12849`... I was only curious if there was a possibility to keep the `0` and convert it to string in runtime

Comment: that is the whole point, if it is a number, it can't be 00123 as php wont allow that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use strpad to do this :

```
str_pad($id , 8 , "0" , STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

This will make a string 8 characters long, zero padded to the left with the integer $id;